# How to request user to input a file location in order to use and read it in the program in Eclipse(Java)

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, file, location

I am making a program that, in one case, requires the program to request the user to input a file location when the file cannot be found in the src folder and the program should be able to run and read it. Any ideas on how to code this in Eclipse(Java)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work out how to fix my problem. All i did was use "scan" from the first Scanner class i made, and put in the 2nd line as "scan.next();".

```
System.out.println("Enter file location");
File myfile = new File(scan.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
System.out.println("Enter file location : ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileLocation = sc.next(); 

try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This reads contents from the file specified by the user. Hope this helps.

Comment: In the output console it prints out "Enter file location" and in this case i enter c:/eclipse/workspace/"memberships.txt". However it comes up with an error: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\eclipse\workspace\"memberships.txt" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect). I know i spelt all the input correctly and the file is located there.

Comment: Remove the double quotes in "memberships.txt" and it will work fine.

Comment: It still didn't work. The file is certainly in that directory and is spelt correctly.

Comment: Just try this. Go to the file location. Right click on the file, click properties  and copy file path from there. After that add /membership.txt. Copy paste this whole thing in user input. It should work.

Comment: And also please don't forget to replace \ with /

Comment: It is still giving the same error. Do i need to type something else in other parts of my code?

Comment: No. And it should be C:/ not c:/

Comment: What about replacing / with \\

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: memberships.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Membership_18634277.main(Membership_18634277.java:51)

Comment: try with a dummy file in the same directory. Make sure it is named something like abc.txt and not abc.txt.txt

Comment: I entered "C:/eclipse/workspace/abc.txt" but it came up with the same error and said "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: memberships.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)". It was supposed to say abc.txt instead of memberships.txt isn't it? I even tried moving the memberships.txt file to the desktop and calling it from the console but that didn't work also.

Comment: I strongly believe that the problem is with filename. You might have given "hide extensions for common files" option ticked in folder options. So memberships.txt might be originally memberships.txt.txt.

Comment: I tried typing in memberships.txt.txt as the file location input but that doesn't seem to work either.